# Showing that union over a collection of connected sets $\{F_n\}$ with $F_i\cap F_j \neq \varnothing, i\neq j$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I am unsure about the argument I've given below, as it seems so much more straightforward than the one given in my reading material. Specifically I can't tell whether I am missing some small technical nuance, which is crucial for this proof. In any case, theorem & proof:

Claim: Let $\{F_n\}$ be a collection of connected sets in a metric space $M$ with $F_i\cap F_j \neq \varnothing, i \neq j$. Then $K = \cup_{n=0}^{\infty}F_n$ is connected.

Proof: Suppose that $K = \cup_{n=0}^{\infty}F_n$ is not connected and let $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ be arbitrary. Then for some $K = X \cup Y$ for some $X, Y \subset M, \overline{X}\cap Y = X \cap \overline{Y} = \varnothing$. Then as $F_k \subset K$, it follows that $F_k = F_k \cap K = F_k \cap (X \cup Y) = (F_k \cap X) \cup (F_k \cap Y).$ Moreover, as $F_k \cap X \subset X$ and $F_k \cap Y \subset Y$, it follows that $\overline{F_k \cap X} \subset \overline{X}, \overline{F_k \cap Y} \subset Y.$ Therefore $\overline{F_k\cap X}\cap (F_k\cap Y) \subset \overline{X}\cap(F_k \cap Y) \subset \overline{X} \cap Y = \varnothing \implies \overline{F_k\cap X}\cap (F_k\cap Y) = \varnothing$. Similarly $\overline{F_k\cap Y}\cap (F_k\cap X) \subset \overline{Y} \cap X = \varnothing \implies \overline{F_k\cap Y}\cap (F_k\cap X) = \varnothing$, implying that $F_k$ is not connected. But $F_k$ is connected. Therefore our original assumption must have been false. Thus $K = \cup_{n=0}^{\infty}F_n$ is connected.

Edit: There was a serious typo that $F_i \cap F_j = \varnothing$, while it should be $F_i \cap F_j \neq \varnothing$ as pointed out by @DavidHartley. I have closed the question as @Oliver Kayende provided a valid counter example to the flawed question.

Comment: You are missing that $\overline{F_k\cap X}\cap (F_k\cap Y) = \varnothing = {F_k\cap X}\cap \overline{F_k\cap Y}$ does not imply $F_k$ is not connected, unless you also show $F_k \cap X$ and $F_k \cap Y$ are non-empty. You also presumably have a typo in the question; it should have each $F_i \cap F_j \neq \varnothing$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP claim is false. The singleton subsets $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\dots$ are connected in $\Bbb R$ and pairwise disjoint but $\Bbb N:=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\;\{n\}$ is not a connected subspace of $\Bbb R$ as $$\Bbb N=((0.5,2.5)\cap\Bbb N)\cup((2.5,\infty)\cap\Bbb N)$$